# Django with Tornado: Django models are not updated on tornado server

Tags: python, django, django-models, tornado, django-managers

I'm accessing Django models from a Tornado server, but I'm stuck on a problem. I've two servers running: one main gunicorn server which serves the whole Django project and other Tornado server for websockets. When I'm adding a model from via main server and then query the queryset from via tornado server, It doesn't return newly added objects in model.

When I restart the tornado server and query the models again, this time I get the all objects.
The problem I think lies in multiple database managers and they are caching the objects and not fetching the objects from database.

Comment: Well, perhaps you should show those managers then?

Comment: those are default managers, but there are two instances of managers